# If else state on Hiding a button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have two buttons in a view. If you tap the button on the left, then the button on the right should toggle whether it is hidden.

I have defined outlets for both buttons but my if else statement is wrong. This is my if else statement:

```
@IBAction func aa(sender: AnyObject) {
    if {
        b.hidden = true
    } else {
        b.hidden = false
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have anything in your if statement

Comment: what do I put in?

Comment: The **condition**. An expression that evaluates to either `true` or `false`. For example, a variable of type `Bool`. Or perhaps a comparison expression like `var1 < var2` . Exactly what that condition is, will depend on when do you want to display your button.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to toggle the `hidden` property of `b` when the function runs you can use:

```
@IBAction func aa(sender: AnyObject) {
    b.hidden = !b.hidden
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your if else statement.  If you would like to use an If else statement, here's how I would do it:

```
if b.hidden = false {
    b.hidden = true
} else {
    b.hidden = false
}
```

Additional info...

In swift 3, to hide buttons what you would want to do is `b.isHidden = true`. The same would apply for showing buttons-`b.isHidden = false.`

Comment: That would work, but paulw11's answer is simpler and cleaner and accomplished the same thing.

Comment: That's true; however I wanted @JC SAM to understand how to use if else statements correctly as well  - I think my answer will still be helpful.

Comment: No worries. You answered the question that was asked. (Voted.)You might want to say " here's how you do it with an if statement, but a better better way would be...

Answer (score 0):

To toggle whether the button is hidden you can just set it to opposite of what it currently is:

For Swift 2:

```
@IBAction func aa(sender: AnyObject) {
    b.hidden = !b.hidden
}
```

For Swift 3:

```
@IBAction func aa(sender: AnyObject) {
    b.isHidden = !b.isHidden
}
```

Comment: I want want button to never hide button is always on and stays constant. Button a controls the show/hiding of button b

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.) not sure why someone down-voted you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
@IBAction func aa(sender: AnyObject) {
    if b.isHidden = false {
        b.hidden = true
    } else {
        b.isHidden = false
    }

}
```